# Truncate multiple tables in one MySQL statement

Tags: sql, truncate

Is there a possibility to truncate with one SQL statement, multiple tables?

Like this:

```
 truncate table #OBJ_AvailabilityTraining, #OBJ_AvailabilityHoliday, #Dates_temp;
```

Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can only truncate a single table with TRUNCATE command. To truncate multiple tables you can use T-SQL and iterate through table names to truncate each at a time.

```
DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1),
        @tableList VARCHAR(MAX),
        @tableName VARCHAR(20),
        @currLen INT

SET @delimiter = ','

SET @tableList = 'table1,table2,table3'

WHILE LEN(@tableList) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @currLen = 
    (
        CASE charindex( @delimiter, @tableList ) 
            WHEN 0 THEN len( @tableList  ) 
            ELSE ( charindex( @delimiter, @tableList  ) -1 )
        END
    ) 

    SELECT @tableName = SUBSTRING (@tableList,1,@currLen )

    TRUNCATE TABLE @tableName

    SELECT tableList = 
    (
        CASE ( len( @tableList ) - @currLen  ) 
            WHEN 0 THEN '' 
            ELSE right( @tableList, len( @tableList ) - @currLen  - 1 ) 
        END
    ) 
END
```

You can have all your table names comma separated in @tableList variable and yes you can truncate multiple tables from different schemas if they are prefixed.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the sp_MSforeachtable stored procedure like so:

```
USE MyDatabase
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?'
```

Or you can create SQL Statement

```
SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TableName%'
```

and run this above SQL statement

Comment: perfect. I used this in SSIS using exec sql to get the list and a foreach loop to iterate through each one. I guess you could do the same in SSMS with a cursor.

Comment: `sp_MSforeachtable` is MSSQL, this question is MySQL.

Comment: When I use your below query, It is  not truncating the tables but just displaying the name of the tables in the output like `Truncate ABC Truncate CDE`

Comment: This statement selects all tables in all databases. How about one database only?

Answer (score 10):

No. But there's an alternative:

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE '+TABLE_NAME+ ';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'your-table-name%'
```

**Example :**

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE '+TABLE_NAME+ ';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TBL_ORDERS_20%'
```

**Now you have below Results for above `Select` Query**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_ORDERS_2001
TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_ORDERS_2002
TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_ORDERS_2003
TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_ORDERS_2004
```

or you can use something like

```
select 'Truncate table ' + TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME in ('Table1', 'Table2')
```

**[Link 1](http://www.dotnetfactor.com/Forum/truncate-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-174.aspx)**

**[Link 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsearch/thread/c1ea411f-22df-4cb4-8b8c-d4e856397895)**

**Update:**

Looking at table in your Example `Query` in your Question

*`truncate table #OBJ_AvailabilityTraining, #OBJ_AvailabilityHoliday, #Dates_temp`*

I think you want to `Truncate` all **temporary tables**.

You can do so with a simple `Query` like this

```
select 'Truncate table ' + TABLE_NAME from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: personally i had to use `SELECT concat('Truncate table ', TABLE_NAME)` to get proper output. But thanks for the general idea!

Answer (score 9):

Just easily enter this MySQL statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE yourtablename1;
TRUNCATE TABLE yourtablename2;
TRUNCATE TABLE yourtablename3;
```

...
and so on.

Change the **yourtablename** with yours.

Don't forget the semicolon ;

Comment: The question was one sql statement ;)

Comment: I know this solution already, but I am happy to see the solution in minimum lines of code, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Bonus example, truncate all tables in one database starting with a string...

```
SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name'
  AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'cache_%';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had to change the code sent by IndoKnight because it throws me an error in the truncate statement so I change the code by this, it is quite similar but the truncate part:

```
DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1),
        @tableList VARCHAR(MAX),
        @tableName VARCHAR(100),
        @currLen INT,
        @truncateStatement VARCHAR(200)

SET @delimiter = ','

SELECT @tableList = COALESCE(@tableList + ', ','') + CAST (TABLE_NAME AS varchar(100))
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'xxx'

    WHILE LEN(@tableList) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @currLen = 
        (
            CASE charindex( @delimiter, @tableList ) 
                WHEN 0 THEN len( @tableList  ) 
                ELSE ( charindex( @delimiter, @tableList  ) -1 )
            END
        ) 

        SELECT @tableName = TRIM(SUBSTRING (@tableList,1,@currLen ))

        SET @truncateStatement = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME('xxx') + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)
        EXEC (@truncateStatement)

        SELECT @tableList = 
        (
            CASE ( len( @tableList ) - @currLen  ) 
                WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                ELSE right( @tableList, len( @tableList ) - @currLen  - 1 ) 
            END
        ) 
    END
```

The trick is using QUOTENAME to put the square brackets to the table name and schema. Maybe IndoKnight solution does not work anymore in more recent version of the database. I hope it helps.