# Can I delete all data in Database MySQL without deleting tables or relationships?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to empty the database of any data, while keeping the relationships and tables as they are

I have no idea if my thinking is right or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just run mysqldump with --no-data

```
mysqldump --no-data -u someuser -p mydatabase
```

You can save it to a .sql file and then drop your database
Then you restore it from the dump

Answer (score 0):

```
truncate table_name;
```

table_name is the table you want to delete all data in it.
truncate only works on tables, so you need to execute truncate table one by one.

Comment: I have to cancel the relationships between the tables, and I have too many tables, and it will take me a long time to cancel and link the relationships again

Answer (score 0):

Use truncate to all table :

```
mysqldump -d -uuser -ppass --add-drop-table databasename > databasename.sql
mysql -uuser -ppass databasename < databasename.sql
```

or you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885101/delete-data-from-all-tables-in-mysql), similar problem.